# How do you retrieve information from Omniauth in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I have tried so many guides and so many tutorials, but whenever I try to retrieve information that Omniauth is supposed to provide after the user accepts the permissions.  Right now I just want a user to log in with Google and access his calendar.

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"},
:controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }

devise_scope :user do
get "/auth/google_oauth2/callback" => 'callbacks#google_oauth2'
end
```

config/initializes/omniauth.rb

```
module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class GoogleAuth < OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleOauth2
    option :name, 'google_auth'
    option :callback_path, '/callbacks/google'
    end
  end
end

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, '<my client id in string>', '<my client secret in string>', {
  access_type: 'offline',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
  callback_path:'http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback'
  prompt: 'select_account consent'
}

 #provider :devloper unless Rails.env.production?
  provider :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
```

end

callbacks_controller.rb

```
class CallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
 def google_oauth2
   @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
   if user.persisted?
        sign_in_and_redirect @user
   else
        session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
   end
 end
end
```

models/user.rb:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
end
```

end

The error this that env["omniauth.auth"] and :provider.  How do I change my files so that Omniauth correctly populates with the user's information and so that I can create a devise user for that session.  The project is at https://github.com/SafaTinaztepe/teemvu.git.

Answer (score 0):

on your `user.rb`, I think it should be

```
user.provider = auth['provider'],
user.uid = auth['uid'],
....
```

Comment: Thanks, but my issue is that the auth part of auth['provider'] is nil.  The environment variable env["omniauth.auth"] is not returning anything which is where Omniauth was supposed to dump its information after the permissions page

Comment: I downloaded your repo. I was running it and first error I got is callback_path needs a comma after it. Secondly, check your credentials in google console. The error you will be getting after the comma fix is the redirect_url is `http://localhost:3000http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback` and I think it has something to do with how you set up your credentials in google